# Metro Style in WPF applications _ Packages differences

Tags: wpf, microsoft-metro

I want to create a metro style application, I did some researches and I found lots of articles and tutorials about that.

But I still need a clear comparison between `Modern UI for WPF` , `Elysium` and `MahApps`.

Testing all of them takes too much time ! I need to learn bout each one's features to decide with which one to start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

first : [Download the WPF Shell Integration Library Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell)

then use this XML Code :

```
<Window x:Class="MyLibrary.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        d:DesignHeight="449"
        d:DesignWidth="677"
        Foreground="White"
        removed="Black">

    <shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <shell:WindowChrome CaptionHeight="35"
                            GlassFrameThickness="0,0,0,1"
                            ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
    </shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(note, you need to have referenced Microsoft.Windows.Shell)

**This is really the Best way to do that.. It will work on all windows versions.**

**Edit:** 
if you want to add Caption Buttons on the top of the window add this XAML code to any control at the top: (button as example)

```
<button shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
```